# mysql regexp returns boolean rather than value

Tags: mysql, regex

according to the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) selecting a REGXP will always produce a boolean (match or non match) but I'm trying to get the result, if it's a match, meaning if I'm doing...

```
select file_id REGEXP '^\d{10}' from my_table;
```

What I want back is not false or true but false or the actual 10 digits that start file_id.

Am I missing something? or is this really how mySQL has implemented regexp?!

I realize that in my case, I can use SUBSTR, but now I'm just curious why they would have deviated from the prescribed norm of how regexp matching works everywhere else.

Comment: I'll hazard a guess - to return a match, the regex implementation has to delve into captured groups and which one the user wants back, which is much more complicated than simply saying "it matches" or "it doesn't match". It would also be a huge performance hit seeing as usually one wishes to use `REGEXP` (note - synonym `RLIKE`) to test for matches, rather than extracting results. `REGEXP` (or `RLIKE`) is just meant to be a more sophisticated `LIKE`.

Comment: [Useful Mysql Regex](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/MySQL_Regular_Expression_Searches)

Comment: @mathematical.coffee, I guess... but if I'm willing to take the performance hit, I don't think mysql should stop me! and I hear what you're saying about the grouping, but that's what MATCH is *supposed to do!!

Comment: @mathematical.coffee was in between some work, so didn't catch that line till I posted my answer, now deleted it. Just send a comment with @ infront to let others know,

Comment: Dr.Dredel You are right, getting the capturing group is not anything extra than matching it since it already will have the capturing group once it is matched, @mathematical.coffee how is it much more complex ?

Comment: Well, suppose my regex was `((.(?!foo))*|([0-9]+)(?=asdf))` (valid but completely meaningless, I made it up). Which capturing bracket should be returned? `\1`, `\2`, or `\3`? And what if there are multiple matches in one field? Return them all? The first one? The third one? This requires storing all the sub-matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your question, "is this really how MySQL has implemented regexp?" the answer is yes. It simply returns a boolean on success or failure to match.

In answer to your question, "why they would shave deviated form the prescribed norm", the answer is that it is more useful in queries to have boolean returns, since you are more often testing for the presence of something, not extracting something, based on a pattern. Extracting things is more often done using procedural languages, not relational databases.

To do what you want it to do, you might want to write a stored procedure that does the necessary string manipulation.