# SQL to look for a particular text

Tags: sql, sql-server, search

What will be the SQL command for the sample data below:

```
Table1  
ID|Description  
1 |Logon Failed. User tempUser1 is unknown
2 |Logon Failed. User Carl is unknown  


Expected result to get only the username after the word "User" and before the word "is"  
ID|Description  
1 |tempUser1  
2 |Carl
```

Thanks,
Ryl

Comment: What is the problem you're running into?  Also, how should SQL-Server know you want the text `tempUser1`?

Comment: I guess you need more than to know how to use `WHERE` and `LIKE`? Please [edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19520651/edit) and explain a little better.

Comment: What is it you want to do? Is it to remove the `Logon Failed. User`and `is unknown`parts from the string and just keep the username? And will the description field contain different types of strings?

Comment: @Matthew & jpw I want to get only the username I updated my example.

Comment: I think you need REGEXP with returning matches - but AFAIK SQL doesn't provide this feature. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662126/mysql-regexp-returns-boolean-rather-than-value

Comment: SQLFiddle isn't playing nice, but I think you should be able to use patindex('user',description) to get the starting point of 'user'.  Add the appropriate number of spaces to get to the beginning of the user name for you starting point.  Then use patindex('is', description) to get an endpoint.  Then substring (description, starting point, endpoint).  I'm sure the numbers will take a bit of tweaking.

Comment: Why not simply use their ID, its same in both tables and match the columns using `JOIN`, that would be  alot simpler..

Comment: If at all possible, you could also try to change your DB-model so you store a userID in the log-table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT 
  ID, 
  SUBSTRING(
    description, 
    CHARINDEX('User', description) + 5, 
    CHARINDEX('is unknown', description) - CHARINDEX('User', description) - 6
  ) AS Description
FROM table1
ORDER BY ID
```

The odd formatting of the substring function is just to fit everything on one page here (to remove scrollbars).

Edit:

This should also work , and be more efficient, if the string always starts with `Logon Failed. User`:

```
SELECT 
  ID, 
  SUBSTRING(Description, 20, CHARINDEX('is unknown', Description) - 21) AS Description
FROM table1
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: Thanks jpw. appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following query, and replace the text or set the length as per your requirement:

```
select substring(column_name,patindex('%tempUser%',column_name),9) from Table_Name where column_name like '%tempUser%'
```